# laravel function to global

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

**I want always to use this function globally of laravel/homestead as description** [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead)

**with this function :**

```
function homestead() {
( cd ~/Homestead && vagrant $* )}
```

**I Use Ubuntu** 

**it will be instead of vagrant** 
**Best regards**

Comment: Do you use one VM for all your projects or multiple VM's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just paste this function in your .bashrc file

```
function hs() {
    cd ~/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead

    command="$1"

    if [ "$command" = "edit" ]; then
        open ~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml
    else
        if [ -z "$command" ]; then
           command="ssh"
        fi

        vagrant "$command"
    fi

    cd -
}
```

Then you can call `hs edit`, `hs up` `hs ssh` etc. from anywhere in your system.

Don't forget to `source ~/.bashrc`